# Which process killed my process

Tags: windows-xp, process, task-manager, kill

One of my applications starts java.exe, but in between this 'java.exe' is killed by some other process.

How can I know which process kills the java.exe. I am using Windows XP SP 2.

Comment: process monitor looking for the word java.exe somewhere but i'm not sure where.

Comment: What you could do is run process monitor capture before and after, and then search for java.exe  For example, if I load cmd.exe and do taskkill /f /im calc.exe  then I do edit..find..calc.exe within process monitor, then it picks out a line from cmd.exe and I can go to properties and see it says taskkill /f /im calc.exe

Comment: How do you know it is being killed as opposed to crashing on its own?